# How to show value labels in Marker View in MPAndroidChart Pie chart?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am using MPAndroidChart Pie chart and want to get a value label when I click on the value. I used the MarkerView interface and managed to get a value itself (e.getY value). However, I want here not the value itself, but its labels. I've tried to put e.getX instead of e.getY, but it returns me 0.0. I am using MPAndroidChart version 3.1.0. My refreshContent method is below:

```
@Override
public void refreshContent(Entry e, Highlight highlight) {
    tvContent.setText("" + e.getX());
    super.refreshContent(e, highlight);
}
```

I created my PieEntry values as following:

```
yVal.add(new PieEntry((float) u.getPoints(), "label 1"));
```